# Using SQL Server native backup and Veritas Backup Exec to backup the database and transaction log on the same database

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a customer who use the Microsoft SQL Server native backup and Veritas Backup Exec to backup the database and transaction log on the same database.

The native backup runs at 5 AM while the Veritas Backup Exec runs at 12 AM and 12 PM. Can the same database be backup by two different backup software and restored correctly?

Sorry if I have missed out some facts.

Comment: What is your concern here? You can take multiple full backup and can restore the same upto that time. If it is about differential backup or log(transaction) backup then, you need to be concerned about LSN being broken and in that case, you should go for Copy only backup for Full backup.

Comment: Would the user be able to restore the database using the native backup software or the Veritas? That is what I am concerned with.

Comment: If you restore backup taken at 5AM, you will get data upto 5AM. If you restore backup of 12AM or 12PM, you will get data upto that time respectively. One full backup is independent of another full backup, Dependency is between Full and Differential Backup. As far as transaction backup is concerned, Yes - you need to consider than other LSN chain will be broken.

Comment: Tell your customer to create a disaster recovery plan, document it, and then test it frequently. This involves restoring the backups that are part of this plan. There is simply no reason to guess or assume or "think it works" here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one backup "solution" (backup path) doing log backups. So, this is your first decision - which one.

Next question is whether you are planning to do differential backups. The backup path *not* doing diff backups should do their full backups using copy_only.

So, one backup path that only does full backups using copy_only so it doesn't affect the other's diff backups.

The other backup path does full, and then possibly also log and diff backups depending on your requirements.

Then you should decide how you expect to restore. Management Studio's restore dialog can be confusing in how it reads the backup history to generate the restore commands. So this is where it becomes extra important to test!

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to configure one of the two backups in copy only:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

It is not strictly disallowed to use two different backup solutions but it exists only one single chain of backup so restore would be a nightmare.

Better to do full and ltog backup with one solution and use the other solution for full backups with copy only option.

Comment: What about the way the user does it; using two sql backup software to backup the database and transaction log on the same database? Would it restore properly?

Comment: reply in edited anwser